# How to define a default dataset in ODBC driver

Tags: ms-access, google-bigquery, odbc

I have a connection that connects bigquery with MS Access.
I could link bigquery object's and view them in MS Access. But when I try to create a query by joining two tables, it shows an error:

```
ODBC-Call Failed
[simba][Bigquery][70] invalid query : Tablename 'tablename' missing dataset while no default dataset is specified in the request.[#70]
```

Below is the use-case ;-

I have got 2 linked table:

1. Table1
2. Table2

When I create a query via `QueryDesign` on **table1** and on execution of the query I can see that data is fetched from bigquery and shown up in MS access.
Similarly when I create an other query on **table2**, I could see the results.

But when I create a query via `QueryDesing` by joining **table1** and **table2**, during execution of the join query, MS access throws the error below:

```
ODBC-Call Failed
[simba][Bigquery][70] invalid query : Tablename 'tablename' missing dataset while no default dataset is specified in the request.[#70]
```

Can someone help to configure the default dataset in ODBC?

Comment: Maybe as a workaround: have you tried creating two queries, one for each table, and create a third query joining the two base queries?

Comment: Have you tried to make the query using the format <dataset>.<table name> on the table name ?

Comment: Hi @Pontnou , Even the third query on two base queries fail "odbc--call failed
[simba][BigQuery](70) Invalid Query:unregonized name "table_name" at [1:170](#70) "

Comment: Hi @ewertonvsilva , i cannot  use .(dot) , because this is a linked table in MS Access , so the dataset and table name is taken by default

Comment: Are you writing the query or using some wizard on access ? If you are writing the query, try to put the query insite the following block, setting the dataset_name ```BEGIN SET @@dataset_id = 'DATASETNAME'; <YOUR QUERY>; END```

Comment: Hi @ewertonvsilva , i have written the query as suggested in ms access but it says " Invalid SQL Statement : expected "Delete' , 'update','insert','select','procedure'  . so the Begin & End block is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the issue, You will have 2 options:

1. Set the dataset on the odbc driver configuration:

- Follow the tutorial on [this link](http://cloud/community/tutorials/bigquery-from-excel) to find the ODBC driver configurations.
- Set the `default dataset` name on this step, editing the user DSN:
  **[image: strong text]**

2. If the probelm persists, then it will indicate an issue on the `odbc simba` connector.

- Open a issue case on [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-tracker), so they can check you log details and provide a more appropriated support.